# What is the difference between corridor and hall way

Tags: comparison

My understanding is that corridor means there is no doors on both sides, and hall way means there are doors leading to rooms on both sides.

Comment: did you at least look up the words in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

[I'm not sure where you got the notion that corridors don't have doors on the sides](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corridor):

> cor·ri·dor noun \ˈkȯr-ə-dər, ˈkär-, -ˌdȯr\
>   : a long, narrow passage inside a building or train with doors that lead to rooms on each side

Native speaker gut check:  I consider them perfect synonyms.

Comment: Seconding this - whether you say corridor or hallway is, at least in my experience, purely a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Good logical reasoning chaps. To further whack the nail into the coffin, it is purely a potato/potato matter if you get what I'm trying to say.  Its just a difference in what I could guess to be British English and American English.